# Как установить focus на элемент?

Tags: html, css

Создал группу иконка+input. Проблема в том, что hover и active - работает, а вот focus нет.
Подскажите, как решить проблему?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.label {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  outline: none;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.input {
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}


/* active */

.label:hover {
  border-color: green;
}

.label:active,
.label:focus {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container">
  <div class="label">
    <span class="icon">
    <i class="far fa-compass"></i>
  </span>
    <input class="input" id="1" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все просто `.label:focus-within`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.label {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  outline: none;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.input {
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}


/* active */

.label:hover {
  border-color: green;
}

.label:active,
.label:focus,
.label:focus-within {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container">
  <div class="label">
    <span class="icon">
      <i class="far fa-compass"></i>
    </span>
    <input class="input" id="1" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Поддержка браузерами `focus-within` в размере 73% немного расстраивает. Но решение подошло, благодарю!

Comment: для ослика придется использовать JS полифил. Например: 
https://gist.github.com/aFarkas/a7e0d85450f323d5e164

Comment: Хотя ради него я бы не заморачивался, достаточно что бы в нем просто работал основной функционал.

Answer (score 0):

Остановился на единственном кросс-браузерном варианте - использование js/jQuery, при активации/потере фокуса - вешаем/убираем класс focus элементу:

```js
$('.label').focusin(function() {
  $(this).addClass('focus');
}).focusout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('focus');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.label {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  outline: none;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.input {
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}


/* active */

.label:hover {
  border-color: green;
}

.label.focus {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="label">
    <span class="icon">
    <i class="far fa-compass"></i>
  </span>
    <input class="input" id="1" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```